# Почему возникает ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image]
возникает ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined", не работает некоторые элементы из за этих ошибках,все элементы стали кривыми

Comment: а что конкретно непонятно в сообщении?

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы предоставили код, который ошибку вызывает. Но без Ванги тут понятно, что у вас не определена переменная `ajaxurl`

Comment: В ошибке прямо так и говорится.. у вас не не обозначена переменная ajaxurl, проверьте где вы обознаяаете переменную ajaxurl и она в области видимости вашей AJAX  функции ?